# Synchronize Pi Camera and LEDs

Tags: camera, led, system-clock

I have a Pi Camera (NoIR) and two sets of LEDs, A and B. The two sets of LED are different in position and wavelength.

I want record video with the Pi Camera so that any consecutive frames be lit by different LEDs. 
Ideally, the resulting video would be:

`frame1: LED A on,  LED B off
frame2: LED A off, LED A on
frame3: LED A on,  LED B off
frame4: LED A off, LED A on
frame5: LED A on,  LED B off
frame6: LED A off, LED A on
...`

I figure this should be done with some synchronization on the camera clock but I have no idea how to access it.

Comment: What fps do you expect? For timelapse e.g., this should not be a problem. For 25fps, well,.... you could try to make led blink as short and strong as possible at this frequency and pray you are fast enough to have no overlaps.